# Why does deg(arcsin(sin(rad(degree)))) not produce degree?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function, python, rounding-error

I have an angle in degrees and I want it to be encoded between $-1, ..., 1$ to make it easier for using in a neural network.

I thought it might be a good idea to first convert the angle into radians and then take the `sin` of it. To get the angle back in degrees, first use `arcsin` and then convert to degrees.

In python (using [NumPy math functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html)) this would look something like this:

`np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(np.sin(np.deg2rad(264.0))))`

but instead of `264` this produces `-84` : why is that?

Comment: Note that $\arcsin$ usually returns angles between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, i.e., angles that are between $-90^{\circ}$  and $90^{\circ}$. So you won't  get back $264^{\circ}$; instead, you get the angle in degrees between $-90^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$ that has the same sine as $264$.

Comment: (In summary, because while $\sin(\arcsin(x))=x$ always holds, $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ only equals $x$ if $x$ is in the "correct" range. $\arcsin$ is not the inverse of the full sine function, it is the inverse of the "restricted sine functions")

Comment: Note that the `np` package isn't required: You get the same (to within floating-point rounding error) result from `math.degrees(math.asin(math.sin(math.radians(264.0))))`.

Comment: I edited your question's tags [as this isn't purely a trigonometric question, this also assumes knowledge of a certain math package]. Please check to make sure I am correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's work this from the inside out:

1. Converting 264° to radians gives 4.60766922526503.
2. Taking the sine gives -0.9945218953682734.
3. Taking the arcsine gives -1.4660765716752375.  Note that this is a **different** number of radians than we got in Step 1, but complies with the identity $\sin(x) = \sin(\pi - x)$.  Arcsine is conventionally defined to have the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} ]$, which does not include the original angle of 264° ≈ 4.608 rad, but does include this new reduced angle of -84° ≈ -1.466 rad.
4. Converting this angle to degrees gives -84.00000000000004, which is just -84 with a slight floating-point error.  Note that 264 + (-84) = 180, reflecting the identity $\sin(x) = \sin(180° - x)$.

In short, the way that $\arcsin$ is conventionally defined ensures that your expression will always return a value in the interval $[-90, 90]$.  If your original angle is outside that range, you'll get a different angle back.

Comment: The definiion of arcsen(x) and the solving of the equation sin(x)=a are different problems. The solution to the first one solves the second one too.

Answer (score 4):

This comes down to the fact that the sine function is not actually invertible, which means we can't say that $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$ for every value of x.

For example, we know that $\sin$ of $0^\circ$ is equal to $0$. However, $\sin$ of $180^\circ$ is equal to $0$, too-- and not only that, but $\sin(360^\circ)=0$, and $\sin(540^\circ)=0$, and $\sin(720^\circ)=0$, etc. So, if we ask, "$\sin$ of what is equal to $0$?" should the answer be $0^\circ$, or $180^\circ$, or one of those other numbers? They all work, so which one should we choose?

What this means is that, in general, the answer to "$\sin$ of what is equal to $x$?" isn't a function, because functions have to produce only one answer.

Still, a function like that would be really useful to have, so we decided to make one anyway. Instead of having $\arcsin(x)$ ask the question "$\sin$ of what is equal to $x$?", we decided to make it ask "$\sin$ of which angle between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ is equal to $x$?"

Then we can confidently say that $\arcsin(0)=0^\circ$, and forget about $180^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ and all those other ones.

Why did we choose to the range $-90^\circ$ to $90^\circ$? Well, on that interval, the function produces a single answer, but beyond that, it's entirely arbitrary. $90^\circ$ to $270^\circ$ would have worked, too, and many others, but we chose $-90^\circ$ to $90^\circ$ because it was our favorite (probably because it has $0$ in it, and $0$ is a nice number).

Taking that back to your example, that's why you're getting $-84^\circ$. As it turns out, $\sin(264^\circ)$ is the same as $\sin(-84^\circ)$. So, when you put in $\arcsin(\sin(264^\circ))$, it computes the value of $\sin(264^\circ)$, then looks for which angle between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ has that value of $\sin$, finds $-84^\circ$, and gives it back to you.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 Issues here :

(1) $y=\sin(x)$ ( & other trigonometric functions ) are **"PERIODIC"** which means that $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x-2\pi)=\sin(x+4\pi)=\sin(x-4\pi)=\cdots=\cdots$

Hence , when we are given the function value , there are multiple Possible $x$ values to generate that function value.
This is unlike non-periodic 1-to-1 functions Eg $y=2x+8$ , where we have $x=(y-8)/2$ to get the inverse function.

In trigonometry , the inverse functions ( eg $x=\sin^{-1}(y)$ ) have to generate the value within 1 cycle of the period , which can be $(0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,+\pi)$.

(2) More-over , $y=\sin(x)$ is symmetric in each half-cycle , that is , 2 $x$ values within a cycle will generate the same $y$ value & the function must return 1 such value.
The general convention is to return the unique value in the range $(-\pi/2,+\pi/2)$ (there are other alternate conventions too)

Coming to your "Degree to radian to Degree" Issue :
When we take Example $x=45,135,360+45,360+135,720+45,720+135,\cdots,-360+45,-360+135,-720+45,-720+135,\cdots$
( where $360$ Degree is $2\pi$ radian ) , then $y=\sin(x)$ will be same $y=\sqrt{2}$.
When we try to invert that $y=\sqrt{2}$ to get back the "original" $x=\sin^{-1}(y)$ value , we will not know what Exactly we had : We will always get back $45$ , which is between $-90$ & $+90$.

Issue is not with "Degree to radian to Degree" , which is 1-to-1 & easy to invert.
Issue is with $\sin^{-1}()$ returning the value in the range $(-\pi/2,+\pi/2)$ [[ $(-90,+90)$ ]] & not returning the unknown "original" value back.
We will encounter the Issue with $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$ when $x$ is outside the range $(-\pi/2,+\pi/2)$
Similar Issue with $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x))$ when $x$ is outside the range $(0,+\pi)$.

We can see these 2 Issues in this Picture :

[image: PERIODIC]

The Sine Curve is "PERIODIC" , where 1 cycle can be the Grey line near the Origin , having Positive $x$ values. The cycle can even be the Blue line , having Positive & Negative $x$ values. The Choice is a convention.

The upper Purple line shows that there are multiple $x$ values with same $y$ value. We even see that there are 2 $x$ values even within a Cycle.
Hence half-cycle will have unique $x$ value matching a given $y$ value. The half-cycle is shown with the Pink line near the Origin , having Positive & Negative $x$ values , along with Positive & Negative $y$ values.

OP Example of $x=264$ will have $\sin()$ value $y=0.99452$. That is shown with the lower Purple line , where the corresponding $x$ value within the Grey cycle is shown with the Grey Square. Within the Pink half-cycle , the $x$ value is $-84$ , shown with the Pink Square , hence $sin^{-1}(0.99452)$ will have to give the Equivalent of $-84$.